# How to mimic liferay's account verification behavior

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, account

In Liferay, If the account verification setting is set to true, Liferay will redirect the user to the Account Verification page everytime they attempt to access the portal so they can validate their email address.

Does anyone know which class is this logic implemented in? I need to implement a similar scenario in which a user who has not provided us with their phone number will always be redirected to a certain page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to PortalRequestProcessor.java [method processPath] for logic.

And to implement your scenario, you can implement LoginPostAction using hook and based on user's information redirect user to page you want.